# Eclipse Java shortcut for "printf"?

Tags: java, eclipse

When coding in Java in Eclipse, is there a shortcut similar to typing "syso" and pressing CTRL+Space for System.out.println(), but for printf instead of println?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can create your own using `eclipse template functionality`.

To create your own template take a look here `Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates`.

For example the `sysout` functionality has this template:

```
System.out.println(${word_selection}${});${cursor}
```

you can create similar for `System.out.print()`

Comment: Hehe, with "sysout" you can see the IBM heritage of Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your own for **printf**:

In preferences choose `Java->editor->templates`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see one in the default completion templates, but you can create your own [template](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-dont-write-c)

Answer (score 0):

I created my own System.out.printf() shortcut on Eclipse.

Simply, go to **Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates**

Click on **New**, then fill the form with the following information:

**Name:** the shortcut you would like to use in the editor (e.g. printf)

**Description:** print formatted text (or any other description)

**Pattern:** *System.out.printf(${word_selection}${});${cursor}*

That's it! Now you can just type "printf" in your editor, followed by [Ctrl + space], then [Enter], and the editor will place a System.out.printf() for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you name the new Templates as pzf (you can also try different combinations and see if that doesn't match any other Template names) it will print the statement right away, without having to press enter. Also, I added inverted commas and commas.

```
System.out.printf("${word_selection}${}",);${cursor}
```